# XSS stored in DVWA

Tags: xss, dvwa

Trying "XSS stored in DVWA" and now I am completely confused. It is not letting me bypass, I tried many inputs and I know what the `preg_replace()` is doing still nothing seems to work for me. I used the `:"img src", "body onload","onmouseoover"` etc but nothing seems to work on this case. I also tried unicoded code but still no luck.

Comment: Have you ensured your security level is low?

Comment: No, I was trying to perform it on High level so the security level is set to high.